# GCP Stackdriver: Create Alert in absence of specific text in logs

Tags: google-cloud-platform, stackdriver, google-cloud-stackdriver

Is there a way in Stackdriver to create an alert based on the **absence** of a specific line in the logs for a specific timeframe (say 1 hour) ?

I am trying to have a way to monitor (and be notified) whether a GKE CronJob did **not** run in the last hour. (was not able to come up with any other way of achieving this)

Answer (score 1):

You can create a log based metric in regards to a specific log entry following the steps [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/). Once that is created, you can create an alert based off of that log based metric following the instructions [here](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/logs-based-metrics/charts-and-alerts#creating_a_simple_alerting_policy_on_a_counter_metric).

You could configure the Alert to trigger when its below a certain threshold for a certain amount of time; however, you cannot define a certain time frame for the alert policy to run. The alert policy will run until it is deleted.